# Disable Button in Details View for a particular row Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am working on `UITableView` and when I select a row it goes into Detail View Controller. I have a Button in Details Controller, all I want to do is disable that button when clicked on it and never enable it again. This button will be in enable state for each row and when clicked on it, it should be disabled.

For eg. This is my table with 4 rows A, B, C, D. When clicked on A it ll take you to its detail controller where we have the button and when I click it , it should be disabled. Now I come back to TableView and click on Row C and the button inside Details view should be enabled and when clicked disable it.

For now I am setting a text and changing color when tapped.

```
 [self.myButton setTitle:@"Checked" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [self.myButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithHex:@"#1ece6c" alpha:1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 self.myButton.enabled = false;
```

Comment: What will happen if you go back and again click "A". Will it be again enabled?

Comment: @SNarula no it will be disabled

Comment: Okay, add a new variable(Bool),for each cell in your array with which you are passing data in Tableview. When you go to details page. Lets say you clicked on 'A' > Move to details page. Click the button and disable it. Also make it false for Button "A". Now, when you will again come to detail page check the variable for that particular button and enable and disable Button interaction accordingly.

Comment: If you can write your whole code here, I'll edit that here.

Comment: you can create a index path array on didselect and just check that, the current index is previously selected or not.

Comment: Prabhat is right just manage index with self.myButton.enabled = false; condition like it's true of false based on you index path array contain the value of index or not

Comment: @SNarula That worked :) Thanx

Comment: @iDeveloper Welcome :)

Comment: @Prabhat Your solution will also work , when the data is more in future. Thanx buddy for the help. Will use your solution as well

Comment: welcome @iDeveloper